# Open Directory not changing password with ldap_modify_replace (PHP)

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, ldap

I want to try to manage Apple's Open Directory using a custom PHP page (since the provided one doesn't give the best feedback).  Since this is new to me, I am testing to see if I can get the change working.  So far I have:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors",1); // Show me
error_reporting(E_ALL);      // the errors!

echo "<h2>LDAP Test (Hub 2) V0.5</h2>";
echo "Connecting ...";

$ds=ldap_connect("od.domain.com");  // must be a valid LDAP server!

ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

echo "connect result is " . $ds . "<br />";

if ($ds) { 
    echo "Binding ..."; 
    $r=ldap_bind($ds,"uid=admin,cn=users,dc=od,dc=domain,dc=com","adminpass");
    echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

    echo "Testing search ... ";
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "cn=users,dc=od,dc=domain,dc=com", "uid=alpha");  
    echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

    echo "Number of entries returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

    echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
        echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
        echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
        echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
    }

    echo "Changing password ... ";
    $newPassword="newpass";
    $encoded_newPassword = "{SHA}" . base64_encode( pack( "H*", sha1( $newPassword ) ) );
    $entry["userPassword"] = "$encoded_newPassword";
    $result=ldap_mod_replace($ds,"uid=alpha,cn=users,dc=od,dc=domain,dc=com",$entry);
    echo " Complete!<br />";

    echo "Closing connection";
    ldap_close($ds);

} else {
    echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
?>
```

Obviously, I intend to make this a little more dynamic.

When I run it, I get positive results on the page (when I echo $result, I get 1 or "True" back).  However, the password isn't changing.  I have a suspicion this might be due to the password encryption, but I am getting no errors back.  I also can't find exactly what encryption I should be using.

This is running on Apache 2.  PHP Version 5.3.28.  I see `--with-ldap=/usr` in the Configure Command entries on a phpinfo() call.

Could anyone assist?

It seems it is writing this attribute, but this is the incorrect attribute to write.  On checking "Directory utility" and "LDAPManager" I can see the "userPassword" attribute (just "Password" on Directory Utility) but not on non edited records.  I do see 2 attributes of "authAuthority" which refer to "Kerberosv5" and "ApplePasswordServer", the latter of which seems to hold an encrypted password.  Any insight is welcome.

Comment: Could you update your post with the versions of software you are using?

Also, how are you determining that the password is not change in Open Directory?

Comment: Added some info.  I can't check the Server application as I can't remote in right now.  I can check the password by using one of the  apps I have which use it for authentication, Xythos and FontExplorer.

Comment: Ok, can you add a couple of lines after the call to `ldap_mod_replace`: `$err = ldap_errno($ds); var_dump($err, ldap_err2str($err));`

Comment: It displays `int(0) string(7) "Success"`

Comment: It's possible the OD server (which is a fork of OpenLDAP) is using something similar to the `ppolicy` overlay, and is hashing passwords on add/modifiy. Try setting the password from PHP without specifically hashing it, and then use `ldapsearch` (authenticating as the rootDN) to verify if the password is stored in clear text or hashed form.